# Ubuntu Linux on Virtual Box display is too big for the window

Tags: display-resolution

[Attcahed is a picture of the resolution being not right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qpvw.png)I am trying to change my screen resolution so that I can see my whole terminal window in my Linux OS,
I use the command xrandr but the only available screen resolution is 640x480 which doesn't work.
Any advice?

Comment: Install virtualbox guest-additions and then the resolution of guest will adapt to the size of the window.

Comment: Have you tried RightCtrl + C ?

Comment: RightCTRL + C doesn't work.
Did I install the right guest-addition? @bistoco

Comment: `ls -l /opt` will list all the guest additions that have been installed. The latest one should match the revision number of virtualbox, which you can get from the Help menu, choose About Virtualbox

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic, but stumble upon it because I also have encountered it.

My solution: use the "Try" option and adjust display resolution setting. 1024x768 is in my experience the minimum required by the installation and will work ok. 1280x960 would also work.
After the new resolution is applied installation window will be fully visible and one can install the guest os.